# calculate x value from normal distribution in matlab

Tags: matlab, normal-distribution

I have data x , with nonzero mean.  I can plot normal distribution with following

```
x=randi([1 20],1,60);
a=mean(x);
b=sqrt(var(x));
x= [-130:1:120];
norm = normpdf(x,a,b);
plot(x,norm)
```

to calculate x value for 97%, I have to see z score for 97% and then use `z=(x-mean)/standard deviation` for  calculation of x value but how can I calculate x value directly by code.

Comment: you take `norm` (maybe round it) and index it where it is closest to 97% and then use the same formula?

Comment: how should it would be done

Comment: well, you can do `cumsum(norm)` to and find the index closest to 97% and read `norm(index)` to get your result? Alternatively (even better) look at `normcdf`

Comment: are you looking for `x = norminv([0.03 0.97],mu,sigma)` ?

Comment: yes  x = norminv([0.03 0.97],mu,sigma) gives solution